# Transformation Rules

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I've managed to obtain general solutions to a cubic polynomial with arbituary constants (x1, x2, x3 are solutions). By using transformation rules, how would I get x1x2x3,x1x2+x2x3+x3x1 and x1+x2+x3.[image: code]

See above the result of finding roots of polynomial.

**Code:**
Input:

```
h[x_] := x^3 + a x^2 + e x + d
s = Solve[h[x] == 0, x]
```

Output:

```
{{x -> -(a/3) - (2^(1/3) (-a^2 + 3 e))/(
3 (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
   3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
    4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(
 1/3)) + (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(
1/3)/(3 2^(1/3))}, {x -> -(a/3) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-a^2 + 3 e))/(
3 2^(2/3) (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
   3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
    4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(
 1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
   3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
    4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(1/3))/(
6 2^(1/3))}, {x -> -(a/3) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-a^2 + 3 e))/(
3 2^(2/3) (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
   3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
    4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(
 1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-2 a^3 - 27 d + 9 a e + 
   3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
    4 a^3 d + 27 d^2 - 18 a d e - a^2 e^2 + 4 e^3])^(1/3))/(
6 2^(1/3))}}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just managed to do it.

Comment: `x1 x2 x3`, `x1 x2+x2 x3+x3 x1` and `x1+x2+x3` are just `-d`, `e` and `-a`. Are you just trying to confirm [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)?

Comment: You might want to look at `SymmetricPolynomial[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
h[x_] := x^3 + a x^2 + e x + d
s = Solve[h[x] == 0, x]
```

Define

```
sol = x /. s
```

Then

```
Total @ sol // FullSimplify
```

> -a

```
Times @@ sol // FullSimplify
```

> -d

```
Total @ (Times @@@ Subsets[sol, {2}]) // FullSimplify
```

> e

Answer (score 0):

If you start with 'transposed' list of solutions,

```
soln = { {x -> firstSolution}, {x -> secondSolution}, {x3 -> thirdSolution} }
```

You can extract a list of solutions with

```
solnList = soln[[ ;;, 1, 2 ]]
(* {firstSolution, secondSolution, thirdSolution} *)
```

and then turn it into a list of rules with

```
solnRules = Thread[ {x1, x2, x3} -> solnList ]
(* { x1 -> firstSolution, x2 -> secondSolution, x3 -> thirdSolution } *)
```

Then you can perform the desired replacements:

```
x1 x2 x3 /. solnRules
x1 x2 + x2 x3 + x3 x1 /. solnRules
x1 + x2 + x3 /. solnRules
```

---

Generalization:

You can generalize this to arbitrarily many solutions with something like

```
solnList = soln[[ ;;, 1, 2 ]];
solnRules = Thread[ Symbol["x"<>ToString@#]& /@ Range@Length@soln -> solnList ]
(* { x1 -> firstSolution, x2 -> secondSolution, x3 -> thirdSolution } *)
```

(The last line above can likely be done more elegantly, possibly using `MapIndexed` rather than `Thread`.)

**Edit**  As mentioned, a (marginally) more elegant solution:

```
solnList = soln[[ ;;, 1, 2 ]];
MapIndexed[Symbol["x" <> ToString@First@#2] -> #1 &, solnList]
(* { x1 -> firstSolution, x2 -> secondSolution, x3 -> thirdSolution } *)
```

Comment: I'm trying to transpose my list of solutions, but it's not evaluating the values of x that was outputted.

Comment: @AlessiaT Could you be more specific and post the code and output?  The best way to do this is to edit the question.

Comment: @AlessiaT Just to be clear, by 'transposed` list of solutions, I was referring to the way `Solve` outputs it.  (The output looks like a column matrix, which is why I referred to it as 'transposed'.)

Comment: I've been trying to do this part for a while now, and tried inputting the transposed list into mathematica again, but managed to do it now! thank you so much, very appreciative!!

Comment: @AlessiaT You're welcome, but [the best way to thank me](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is to upvote and (after some time passes to allow others to answer) to accept my answer.